# MeteorJS: How to get id to load from collection

Tags: html, meteor

I'm trying to load an array (with simple text) and trying to load it up on the template whenever it is called. How do I get the ID from that specific item to get the array that I stored in it?

HTML Template:

```
<template name="commentMarker">
    <div id="viewMarker">
        <h3 id="markerTitle">{{markerName}}</h3>
        <h6 id="markerCategory">{{markerCategory}}</h6>
        <br>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Description</legend>
            <p>{{markerDescription}}</p>
        </fieldset>
        <form id="commentForm"> 
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Comments</legend>
                <input type="text" id="markerId" name="idForComment" value={{markerId}}>
                <textarea rows="3" cols="19" name="comment" id="commentArea" placeholder="Insert your comment here..."></textarea>
                {{#each comments}}
                    <p id="oneComment">{{this}}</p>
                {{/each}}
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Comment" class="commentButton">
            <input type="submit" value="Close" class="exitButton">
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
Template.commentMarker.helpers({
comments(){
        alert(template.find("#markerId").value);
        if(commentArray.length===0) return;
        else return commentArray;
    }});
```

This is where I insert the comment into the collection's item and it's working fine

```
Template.commentMarker.events({
    'click .commentButton': function(e, template){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = template.find("#markerId").value;
        var comment = template.find("#commentArea").value;
    Points.update(id, { $push: { comments: comment }});
        commentArray = Points.findOne(id).comments;
        template.find("#commentArea").value = ' ';
    }
```

I tried with `commentArray` as a global variable which still is. But I'm at loss how I can get the Id from that specific item, I even put it's Id (with hidden display) in the form to actually be able to insert the comment. But it doesn't help me with showing the comments because I cannot seem to get to this field in the Template.helpers ...

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to do. It's almost like as if you are displaying the comments right after you updated in to the collection. It looks like you are doing this entirely on local and not a online collection.

However, storing it as a session would work...or reactive var. Might not be the best solution tho. Basically replace `commentArray = Points.findOne(id).comments;` with:

```
Session.set('comments', Points.findOne(id).comments)
```

Then to get it out in helpers:

```
let commentArray = Session.get('comments')
```

It's not safe to use it all the time tho for sensitive data. Also try catch the findOne(id).comments because it does produce errors if it happen to not find it.

NOTE: If you are going to use Meteor.Methods, you cannot use Session. You have to return the id and find it in your helpers.

Comment: Yes,tried it and worked. Thank you :)  The point is to return an array of simple text(comments) to then load up everything in the template whenever a marker(on the map) was triggered. Until I find the "safe way" of doing this , this will work out fine. Thank you